# how to start new activity using button in android studio

Tags: android

Kindly someone explain, why is it not working?

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, signup.class);
        startActivity(intent);                
    }
});
```

signup word is giving error in the line given below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, signup.class);
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly, explain clearly with the issue.

Comment: If you have issue with this not working, there is solid chance logcat shows the error. We need to see it.

Comment: Did you add the activity in manifest file?

Comment: Do you have an activity called (exactly) `signup` ?

Comment: Yes i did, Manifest has the activity.

Comment: What kind of error. Please, be more specific.

Comment: A red line comes under (this, signup.class);

Comment: Hover over it or look in your status bar. There should be a text that describes the error.

Comment: Im pretty sure you have to use your mainactivity.this , beucase only this is reference to the listener object.

Answer (score 0):

If your current activity is called Main use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, signup.class);
```

When you put only `this`, `this` is reference of the OnClickListener object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Classname.this`

For example:

```
Intent _intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , signup.class ) ;
```

Next time , pls try to come up with some logs/error description

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, signup.class);
```

Should be like this:
    Intent intent = new Intent(YouCurrentActivity.this, signup.class);
Replace YouCurrentActivity with the name of the activity that you are currently coding in. The error occurs because you cannot refer to the Activity name with "this" in an inner class. e,g in an onClickListener.

Regards from Iran,
   Gabriel